# Хранить длинные дробные числа в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо сохранить в базу число вида 1234567890.123456 (6 цифр после запятой, 10 перед запятой)

В decimal оно не влазит, хранить копейки в int страшно и неудобно, а double дает погрешности, что неприемлемо при финансовых операциях.

Почему бы не хранить число как обычный текст?

Comment: *В decimal оно не влазит* Кто Вам сказал такую глупость? `DECIMAL(16, 6)` или более...

Comment: akina, спасибо

Ипатьев, ну а если сортировка не нужна?

Answer (score -1):

> Почему бы не хранить число как обычный текст?

Сортировка например. Ты же не хочешь чтобы 9 было больше 10?